# Leaflet.draw style messed up in react component

Tags: leaflet, styles, leaflet-draw

In my react project, I use the leaflet as the map library. And I didn't use the `react-leaflet` package, instead I use the original leaflet library.

Now I want to add the `leaflet-draw` plugin, I already install the `leaflet-draw` npm package, and my setup is as following:

```
import 'leaflet-draw'
import './leaflet-draw.less'

class GLMap extends Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    ...
    this.setUpLeafletDraw()
    this.map.on('draw:created', this.leafletDrawHandler)
  }

  leafletDrawHandler = (e) => {
    console.log('11111', e.layer._latlngs)
    const type = e.layerType
    const layer = e.layer

    if (type === 'marker') {
      layer.bindPopup('A popup!')
    }
    this.drawnItemsLayer.addLayer(layer)
  }

  setUpLeafletDraw = () => {
    // this.drawnItems is the layer contains the drawn features
    this.drawnItemsLayer = new L.FeatureGroup()
    this.map.addLayer(this.drawnItemsLayer)
    var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
      edit: {
        featureGroup: this.drawnItemsLayer
      }
    })
    this.map.addControl(drawControl)
  }
}
```

In the above code, `this.map` is the leaflet Dom instance. So far the functions of the leaflet draw can work well.

But the issue is the style of the toolbar is messed up as following:

[image]

So what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely  `leaflet-draw` CSS file is missing which contains declarations for `.leaflet-draw-toolbar`.

It could be *imported* from `leaflet-draw` package like this:

```
import "leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw-src.css";
```

or referenced via `public/index.html` from CDN like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-draw@latest/dist/leaflet.draw-src.css" />
```

Here is [a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ffuykq)